# Cassandra Key Cache

Tags: cassandra

Cassandra Key cache is a map structure where  key is {sstable_file_descriptor+partition_key} and value is partition offset, now why Cassandra during read, checks all sstables (using bloom filter), if the data may present in that stable. Why can't key cache be like partition_key=sstable_file_descriptor+offset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its actually `(tableid, indexName, descriptor, partition_key)` (KeyCacheKey extends CacheKey). The same partition key can exist on multiple tables, and on multiple sstables within them. In order to key by just the key you would need additional structure which would be quite a bit more coordination and contention.

The keycache does not store all data either, only things considered to be likely to get a hit based on Window TinyLfu algorithm. There are potentially billions of keys in a single table so it cannot store them all. The absence from the keycache does not ensure that it does not exist so the bloom filter must be checked anyway. Something to note too, the BF check is in memory and very fast. If the BF passes it checks the cache next. Before any of this it actually also filters based on the range of columns and tokens within an sstable, and skips ones whose data would be tombstoned by the min/max timestamps (see queryMemtableAndDiskInternal).